# Retrieving specific class type from generic class type?

Tags: java

I have below the class.

```
public class BaseRequest<T extends SomeObject>  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * serial version UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2602178514139825116L;

    private Class<T> classType;

    public BaseRequest(Class<T> classType){
        this.classType=classType;
    }



    public Class<T> getClassType() {
        return classType;
    }



}
```

Now SomeObject has subclasses as below.

```
SomeObjectOne.java
SomeObjectTwo.java
SomeObjectThree.java
```

Clients instantiates above class as below.

```
BaseRequest request = new BaseRequest(SomeObjectTwo.class);
```

Now in service method i have to get the class type passed by the user using its get method.

```
       public void someServiceMethod(BaseRequest<T> request){

         //here i need to get the corresponding exact class type using getter.
        Class requestedDomainObjectType = request.getClassType();
        //Now how can i type cast it to respective class type?

        //Is it possible to get exact passed class type?
//I need to get wrapped .class from requestedDomainObjectType 

    //from requestedDomainObjectType  i should get SomeObjectOne.class/SomeObjectTwo.class

        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - partly due to your use of the raw type when constructing `request`. Did you actually mean to use `BaseRequest<SomeObject>`?

Comment: Please edit your question to be clearer then. (It's not even clear to me that that would compile...)

Comment: Jon, i need to get the .class which is wrapped by Class requestedDomainObjectType in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not cast anything. Since method `getClassType()` is generic you should be able to write:

`Class<T> requestedDomainObjectType = request.getClassType();`

This line should be compiled well without any warning.

Comment: AlexR, again how can i get the getter methods of requestedDomainObjectType ? Thanks!

Comment: Method[] methods1 = requestedDomainObjectType.getDeclaredMethods(); // you can exclude Objects methods from this Array. i.e.: Method[] methods2 = Object.class.getDeclaredMethods(); and remove all these methods2 from methods1